# how to compare one value with the whole column in SQL?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have the following data:

```
Policy Number: Amount:   Min Price: 
100              100          70
101              200
102              300
103              50
```

Here the minimum price is set for 70.

How can I get the following result:

```
Policy Number:  Amount after min price:
100                       100
101                       200
102                       300
103                       70
```

I mean I can't compare one value with the whole column without changing the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this using MS Access inline if function `IIF`

```
SELECT iif([amount] < [min_price], [min_price], [amount])
```

Comment: that is smart, I totally forgot to use the iif statement...thanks!

Comment: No problem, don't forget to finish the whole cycle to your questions; if this answer solved your question, please mark the question as answered by checking the box next to this answer.  This helps keep the community clear, concise, and builds up your own reputation which will only benefit you.